# What is the screenshot shortcut on 17.10 when using Unity?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

Did the screenshot shortcut keys change in 17.10?

Those documented on https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html no longer work, and if I create an additional one from the keyboard settings to run gnome-screenshot it's simply ignored.

I had it work perfectly before this update.

Comment: It seems it's now using the Super key instead of Ctrl. For my particular use case Super-Shift-Print can now be used to capture a part of the screen selected with the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You can hold CTrl and Shift and Print Screen and it will save it to your clipboard instead of your Pictures directory

Comment: Doesn't work on my machine from Unity.I don't get asked to select the screen region that would be captured and nothing is captured to my clipboard nor saved to the Pictures folder.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcuts still work. The change is that screenshots are now automatically saved to the Pictures folder in your home directory.

Comment: No, they don't...

Comment: @faramka I just booted a 17.10 live system and tried the shortcuts. They do work.

Answer (score 0):

Some keyboard shortcuts no longer work with Ubuntu 17.10 Unity. Here is my workaround:

```
sudo aptitude install compizconfig-settings-manager
ccsm &
```

Goto "Commands" under "General". Under the "Commands" tab add `/usr/bin/gnome-screenshot` in one of the (empty) lines. Goto next tab "Keybindings". Press the "Disabled" button on the line corresponding to the line where you added `/usr/bin/gnome-screenshot`. Press "Grab key combination" in the popup window and press <kbd>Print</kbd>. Press <kbd>Ok</kbd> to close the popup window. The button on the line in the `ccsm`window should now show as <kbd>Print</kbd>. You can now close the `ccsm` window.

Test with <kbd>Print</kbd>. The familiar "Screenshot" window with filename selection should now appear.

Multiple other keybindings can be added, e.g., one to `gnome-screenshot -a` for an area-selected screenshot.